# Looping through multiple lists

Tags: r, for-loop

How can one loop through multiple data sets in R, it seems a little elusive from Python.

We have 4 lists and want to simply remove all missing values.

Example:

```
a <- c(1,2,3, NA)
b <- c(1,NA,3, NA)

e <- c(1,2,3, 4)
f <- c(NA,2,3, NA)

is.na(a_df) ## -> TRUE

na_list = list(a, b, e, f)
```

What has been tried:

1. Duplicating the code 4 times, which is DRY but works.
2. 

```
for (lst in na_list){
  lst <- zoo::na.aggregate(lst)
}
```

3. Using Lappy

```
na_list <- lapply(na_list, zoo::na.aggregate)
> na_list
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 2

[[2]]
[1] 1 2 3 2
```

but..

```
> a 
[1]  1  2  3 NA
```

Comment: Please don’t type in all caps - it is seen as shouting and considered rude.

Comment: `lapply` and similar are your friends. Read the online help.

Comment: Hi limey, care to share an example of solving this, been struggling with "lappy" particularly. Thanks

Comment: Please make a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) or [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with a sample input and your expected output.

Comment: `pred_list <- lapply(pred_list, zoo::na.aggregate)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have revised according to updated question. Note that the input now shown in the question are numeric vectors, not R lists.

First create a named list L using mget and then apply na.aggregate to each component of L and finally write the components back out to the global environment;  however, you might want to just keep the result as L2 since it is harder to debug code that overwrites variables.

```
library(zoo)

nms <- c("a", "b", "e", "f")

L <- mget(nms)
L2 <- lapply(L, na.aggregate)
list2env(L2, .GlobalEnv)
```

This would also work in place of the last 3 lines.

```
for(nm in nms) assign(nm, na.aggregate(get(nm)))
```

Comment: Thanks so much for pointing out the errors, my apologies.

Edited the questions to something reproducible, the data sets are lists not **data frames**, and applying a *lappy* although works but not reproducing for each item in the list. Kindly help review.

Comment: Thanks so much! 
```for(nm in nms) assign(nm, na.aggregate(get(nm)))```

worked fine.